# How to communicate with “Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Embedded Controller” driver?

Tags: controller, driver, acpi

I'd like to communicate with an Embedded Controller device in a Notebook through I/O ports 62/66. When running on XP, the communication might collide with "Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Embedded Controller" driver which does the same thing. Therefore, I’d like to know whether (and how) I can communicate with I/O ports 62/66 using this driver. In addition, any informative link about what this driver is doing and how, will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge 62/66 is for key board controller. I need to test how EC will impact communicating with this ports if you already have a solution please post it here.